# Plugin to hide image in excerpt

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, post-thumbnails, images

I was looking for a plugin that will enable me to hide an image on the excerpt, but show it on the single post view. Anyone knows if there is any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) this is how it is supposed to work out of the box. Maybe I misunderstood the question, but by default the excerpt should strip html tags and graphics.

Comment: +1 But I think he got `the_post_thumbnail();` or similar in his archive, home, whatever pages that he needs to remove.